# Client information

Tags: c#, .net, environment

Within C# I'm planning to build a Client Class that would be populated with the Environment information such as :

- Logged On User
- Is Administrator
- Language
- Laptop / Desktop
- Processor
- Memory
- Disk Space available

I have a few questions in regards to this,

- Are there any libraries out there that I can use without creating my own
- if not, What's the best ways to get this information

**basically whats he best way to go about compiling this information**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Environment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) has what you need:

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/420.html